# Raspberry Gammu No response in specified timeout. Probably the phone is not connected

Tags: raspberry-pi

I use gammu with my TP-LINK dongle for a while in my Raspberry PI 3B+. Everything worked fine (after hard configuration). Yesterday I tried to change the SIM card and gammu stop working. So I switched and put the old SIM card again, tried a lot of configurations but gammu wont reconize my SIM anymore...
I have this error when starting gammu-smsd :

```
gammu-smsd[1110]: Starting phone communication...
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: [Gammu            - 1.40.0]
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: [Connection       - "at"]
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: [Connection index - 0]
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: [Model type       - ""]
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: [Device           - "/dev/ttyUSB0"]
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: [Running on       - Linux, kernel 4.14.98-v7+ (#1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT 2019)]
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: Serial device: DTR is up, RTS is up, CAR is down, CTS is down
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: Setting speed to 115200
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: [Module           - "auto"]
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: Escaping SMS mode
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x02/2
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: 1B |0D                                                          ..              
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: Sending simple AT command to wake up some devices
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x03/3
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: 41A|54T|0D                                                      AT.             
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: [Retrying 1 type 0x00]
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x03/3
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: 41A|54T|0D                                                      AT.             
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: Enabling echo
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x05/5
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: 41A|54T|45E|311|0D                                              ATE1.           
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: [Retrying 1 type 0x00]
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x05/5
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: 41A|54T|45E|311|0D                                              ATE1.           
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: Phone does not support enabled echo, it can not work with Gammu!
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: It might be caused by other program using the modem.
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: See <https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/faq/general.html#echo> for help.
gammu-smsd[1110]: gammu: Init:GSM_TryGetModel failed with error TIMEOUT[14]: No response in specified timeout. Probably the phone is not connected.
```

My gammu-detect :

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# gammu-detect 
; Configuration file generated by gammu-detect.
; Please check The Gammu Manual for more information.

[gammu]
device = /dev/ttyUSB0
name = Phone on USB serial port TP-LINK__Incorporated TP-LINK_HSPA+_Modem
connection = at

[gammu1]
device = /dev/ttyUSB1
name = Phone on USB serial port TP-LINK__Incorporated TP-LINK_HSPA+_Modem
connection = at

[gammu2]
device = /dev/ttyUSB2
name = Phone on USB serial port TP-LINK__Incorporated TP-LINK_HSPA+_Modem
connection = at
```

Here is my gammu-smsdrc :

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# cat /etc/gammu-smsdrc
; Configuration file generated by gammu-detect.
; Please check The Gammu Manual for more information.

[gammu]
GammuCoding = utf8
GammuLoc = fr_FR.UTF8
device = /dev/ttyUSB0
name = Phone on USB serial port TP-LINK__Incorporated TP-LINK_HSPA+_Modem
connection = at

[gammu1]
GammuCoding = utf8
GammuLoc = fr_FR.UTF8
device = /dev/ttyUSB1
name = Phone on USB serial port TP-LINK__Incorporated TP-LINK_HSPA+_Modem
connection = at

[gammu2]
GammuCoding = utf8
GammuLoc = fr_FR.UTF8
device = /dev/ttyUSB2
name = Phone on USB serial port TP-LINK__Incorporated TP-LINK_HSPA+_Modem
connection = at

# SMSD configuration, see gammu-smsdrc(5)
[smsd]
service = files
CheckSecurity = 0
logfile = /var/log/gammu-smsd.log
# Increase for debugging information
debuglevel = 4
RunOnReceive = /var/www/html/RaspiSMS/parseSMS.sh
RunOnFailure = /var/spool/gammu/on-error.sh
# Paths where messages are stored
inboxpath = /var/spool/gammu/inbox/
outboxpath = /var/spool/gammu/outbox/
sentsmspath = /var/spool/gammu/sent/
errorsmspath = /var/spool/gammu/error/

SMSC=+33695000695

ResetFrequency = 0
ReceiveFrequency = 60
StatusFrequency = 0
CheckBattery = 0
CheckSignal = 0
CheckNetwork = 0
CommTimeout = 60
SendTimeout = 60
LoopSleep = 10
CheckSecurity = 0
```

But when I try a Gammu identify :

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# gammu identify
No response in specified timeout. Probably the phone is not connected.
```

Here are the revelent syslog when I boot the rpi:

```
raspberrypi kernel: [    5.396897] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=2357, idProduct=f000
raspberrypi kernel: [    5.396917] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
raspberrypi kernel: [    5.396926] usb 1-1.4: Product: TP-LINK HSPA+ Modem
raspberrypi kernel: [    5.396935] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: TP-LINK, Incorporated
raspberrypi kernel: [    5.396943] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 863745011345804
[...]
usb_modeswitch: switch device 2357:f000 on 001/004
[...]
raspberrypi kernel: [    7.061466] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
raspberrypi kernel: [    7.194309] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=2357, idProduct=9000
raspberrypi kernel: [    7.194326] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
raspberrypi kernel: [    7.194335] usb 1-1.4: Product: TP-LINK HSPA+ Modem
raspberrypi kernel: [    7.194345] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: TP-LINK, Incorporated
raspberrypi kernel: [    7.194353] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 863745011345804
[...]
raspberrypi kernel: [    7.337716] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
raspberrypi kernel: [    7.339617] option 1-1.4:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
raspberrypi kernel: [    7.340044] usb 1-1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
raspberrypi kernel: [    7.340420] option 1-1.4:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
raspberrypi kernel: [    7.340806] usb 1-1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
raspberrypi kernel: [    7.341234] option 1-1.4:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
raspberrypi kernel: [    7.342861] usb 1-1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[...]
raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started USB_ModeSwitch_1-1.4.
raspberrypi dhcpcd[422]: wwan0: soliciting a DHCP lease
raspberrypi kernel: [    8.312614] scsi 0:0:0:0: CD-ROM            TP-LINK  MMC Storage      2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
raspberrypi kernel: [    8.315256] scsi 0:0:0:1: Direct-Access     TP-LINK  MMC Storage      2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
```

I have no more idea to make my dongle work again with gammu...

Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just seems my dongle were broken. I bought another one and it works again